# Search table columns for values over a certain length

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

So I have a database with many tables that have a column that contains a GL Account value (for financial purposes). The column name varies by table (i.e. in one table the column is called "gldebitaccount" and in another table it's called "glcreditaccount"). I was able to find all combinations of table / column pairs using the following query:

```
SELECT c.name AS ColName, t.name AS TableName
FROM sys.columns c
    JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE c.name LIKE '%gl%acc%'
```

This query returns close to 100 pairs of tables/columns. I am trying to find any value in any of those table/column pairs that exceeds 25 chars in length. For an individual table/column, I'd typically use:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableName
WHERE LEN(columnName)>25
```

I want to avoid having to run that query 100 times with each pair. Is there any way I can do a "for each" (which I know is frowned upon in SQL since everything should be set-based). I've done sub-SELECT statements before, but not any that involved change the table in the FROM clause. Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks all! I'll try each solution tomorrow and see what works best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet another solution with dynamic SQL.

But now without cursors. It uses FOR XML statement and should be much faster.

```
DECLARE @sqlstatement VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sqlstatement =
    REPLACE (
        STUFF ( (
            SELECT 'UNION ALL SELECT ''' + t.name + ''' as TableName, '''
                + c.name + ''' AS ColumnName, '
                + c.name + ' AS Value FROM '
                + t.name + ' WHERE LEN (' + c.name + ') ' + CHAR(62) + ' 25'
            FROM sys.columns c
            INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
            WHERE c.name LIKE '%gl%acc%'
            FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 10, '')
        , '&gt;', '>')

EXEC (@sqlstatement)
```

You may want to add extra filter for columns by their type and max_length:

```
INNER JOIN sys.types ty ON c.system_type_id = ty.system_type_id
    AND (
        ty.name IN ('text', 'ntext')
        OR (
            ty.name IN ('varchar', 'char', 'nvarchar', 'nchar')
            AND (c.max_length > 25 OR c.max_length = -1)
    )
```

Comment: I chose yours as the answer because it also displayed the value that was causing the issues. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As the previous answer, the solution will need dynamic SQL. Here is a way that uses both dynamic SQL and cursors, and you can expect slow performance, so use at your own risk:

```
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(128), @ColumnName NVARCHAR(128) 
DECLARE @Query NVARCHAR(4000)

DECLARE CC CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT QUOTENAME(t.name), QUOTENAME(c.name)
FROM sys.columns c
INNER JOIN sys.tables t 
    ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE c.collation_name IS NOT NULL
AND c.max_length > 25 AND c.name LIKE '%gl%acc%';

CREATE TABLE #Results(TableName NVARCHAR(128), ColumnName NVARCHAR(128));

OPEN CC
FETCH NEXT FROM CC INTO @TableName, @ColumnName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @Query = 'IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM '+@TableName+'
                            WHERE LEN('+@ColumnName+') > 25)
                  INSERT INTO #Results
                  VALUES(@TableName,@ColumnName)'
    EXEC sp_executesql  @Query, 
                        N'@TableName NVARCHAR(128),@ColumnName NVARCHAR(128)', 
                        @TableName, 
                        @ColumnName;
    FETCH NEXT FROM CC INTO @TableName, @ColumnName
END
CLOSE CC
DEALLOCATE CC

SELECT *
FROM #Results
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an option without cursors that also doesn't add XML overhead. Note that it also protects you from potential type conflicts (e.g. try the others in a database with hierarchyid columns, like AdventureWorks), from table or column names with apostrophes, and from table names that exist in more than one schema.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

CREATE TABLE #Results
(
  SchemaName NVARCHAR(128), TableName  NVARCHAR(128), ColumnName NVARCHAR(128)
);

SELECT @sql += N'INSERT #Results SELECT ''' 
    + REPLACE(s.name,'''','''''') + ''',''' 
    + REPLACE(t.name,'''','''''') + ''',''' 
    + REPLACE(c.name,'''','''''') + '''
  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) 
   + '.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + ' WHERE 
   LEN(' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ') > 25);
 '
FROM sys.columns AS c
INNER JOIN sys.tables AS t
ON c.[object_id] = t.[object_id]
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
ON t.[schema_id] = s.[schema_id]
WHERE 
(
  c.system_type_id IN (35,99) -- text,ntext
  OR (c.system_type_id IN (167,231) -- varchar,nvarchar, could be max
      AND c.max_length > 25 OR c.max_length = -1)
  OR (c.system_type_id IN (175,239) -- char, nchar
      AND c.max_length > 25)
)
AND c.name LIKE N'%gl%acc%';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

SELECT SchemaName, TableName, ColumnName FROM #Results;
```

Comment: I believe `'... ''' + REPLACE(..., '''', '''''') + ''' ...'` could also be rewritten as `'...' + QUOTENAME(..., '''') + '...'`, since the expression is applied to names only. Or is there a potential issue with using `QUOTENAME` like that? Don't remember coming across any but I haven't used QUOTENAME with quotation marks much.

Comment: @AndriyM if you have managed to call a schema or table or column name with an apostrophe in it, you need to escape it to embed it directly into the dynamic SQL insert statement into the #temp table. Otherwise it ends up as `INSERT #foo SELECT 'my'column'` which will fail with a syntax error. `QUOTENAME` just puts square brackets around the string so it is valid to insert, but it does not prepare the string to be embedded in another string. Try: `CREATE TABLE dbo.x([y'z] INT); SELECT 'SELECT ''' + QUOTENAME(name) + ''';' FROM sys.columns WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.x');`

Comment: Actually, what I meant was this: `CREATE TABLE dbo.x([y'z] INT); SELECT 'SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(QUOTENAME(name), '''') + ';' FROM sys.columns WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID('dbo.x');`. The script in your answer already has the inner QUOTENAME bit. The outer one replaces the REPLACE. (Note that the surrounding quotation marks that you are adding explicitly when using REPLACE are no longer needed when QUOTENAME(name, '''') is used.)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create dynamic SQL because you cannot dynamically specify the source table. You could do this using a cursor, or write a select statement that makes a row for each statement you need to run. This shows how to do it with a cursor. You problem looks like an acceptable usage for a cursor:

```
DECLARE @ColName VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @SomeSQL VARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
    SELECT c.name AS ColName, t.name AS TableName
    FROM sys.columns c
        JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
    WHERE c.name LIKE '%gl%acc%'

OPEN db_cursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @ColName, @TableName;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

    -- you need to make dynamic SQL
    SELECT @SomeSQL = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @TableName + ' WHERE LEN(' + @ColName + ') > 25;'
    PRINT(@SomeSQL + CHAR(10));

    -- you could execute it directly if you wish.
    --EXEC (@SomeSQL);

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @ColName, @TableName;

END  

CLOSE db_cursor;
DEALLOCATE db_cursor;
```

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't sure if you needed to do anything with the results, but this will return the records that meet the criteria you posted in your question

```
Declare @TableName sysname
Declare @ColName sysname
Declare @dynamic_SQL varchar(MAX)


Declare some_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT c.name AS ColName, t.name AS TableName
FROM sys.columns c
    JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE c.name LIKE '%gl%acc%'

OPEN some_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM some_cursor INTO @ColName, @TableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
Begin
    select @dynamic_SQL = '
    Select *
    From ' + @TableName + '
    Where LEN('+ @ColName +') > 25
    '
    exec (@dynamic_SQL)

    FETCH NEXT FROM some_cursor INTO @ColName, @TableName
End

CLOSE some_cursor
DEALLOCATE some_cursor
```